# Why are all Parent Composables of a nested Composable Recomposed?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple test app:

MainActivity:

```
        ...
        setContent {
            TestTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    TestScreen()
                }
            }
        }
        ....
```

TestScreen:

```
@Composable
fun TestScreen(testViewModel: TestViewModel = viewModel()) {
    Log.i("Test", "A")
    Column {
        Log.i("Test", "B")
        Column {
            Log.i("Test", "C")
            Column {
                Log.i("Test", "D")
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = testViewModel.textField,
                    onValueChange =  testViewModel::updateTextField
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TestViewModel:

```
class TestViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var textField by mutableStateOf("")
        private set

    fun updateTextField(v: String) {
        textField = v
    }
}
```

For every click on the keyboard for the `OutlinedTextField`, I see all logs for `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`. My expectation was that I would actually see no logs after the initial composition, as `OutlinedTextField` is the only dependent of the `textField` State.

Why are all the nested composables recomposed, for every keystroke?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Column` is an inline function. `Column` is very simple and the code that would be required to skip it is more costly than just executing it again.

For example, there are no lambda allocations in the example presented even though `testViewModel` is captured by all of them. As `Column` and `Row` are used frequently, this saving is quite significant over an entire application.

In general, I recommend you don't optimize recomposition like this unless you have a trace in hand that shows that the recomposition is what is causing the jank. Usually it is new item creation in a lazy list for which avoiding the overhead for fine grain skipping reduces the jank.

If you need more skipping granularity you can,

1. Factor the function into smaller functions (that are not `inline`).
2. Introduce a `Skippable` or similar and surround the block that needs to be skipped with it.

```
@Composable
fun Skippable(content: @Composable () -> Unit) = content()
```

Then the above could use it like,

```
@Composable
fun TestScreen(testViewModel: TestViewModel = viewModel()) {
    Log.i("Test", "A")
    Column {
        Skippable {
            Log.i("Test", "B")
            Column {
                Log.i("Test", "C")
                Column {
                    Log.i("Test", "D")
                    OutlinedTextField(
                        value = testViewModel.textField,
                        onValueChange =  testViewModel::updateTextField
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or, since you are just using `Column` to test skipping you can just replace `Column` with `Skippable`

```
@Composable
fun TestScreen(testViewModel: TestViewModel = viewModel()) {
    Log.i("Test", "A")
    Skippable {
        Log.i("Test", "B")
        Skippable {
            Log.i("Test", "C")
            Skippable {
                Log.i("Test", "D")
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = testViewModel.textField,
                    onValueChange =  testViewModel::updateTextField
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh, above comment was truncated so:

Oh~ Column being an inline function explains a lot! And Column's implementation doesn't contain any non-inline Composable; it directly uses the low-level Compose mechanisms. So my TestScreen effectively had no nesting of Composables.
Thank you!